# Get a specific point on the map to get location in Place picker

Tags: flutter, google-maps

How to get the location of a specific point on the place picker plugin? I need to get the lat and long of a specific point other than searching in the above textbox. Is there a way to touch an area and get the location? This is my current code. Thank you.

```
PlacePicker(
            apiKey: "000000000000000000000000000000000",
            initialPosition: HomeScreen.kInitialPosition,
            useCurrentLocation: true,
            selectInitialPosition: true,

            //usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
            onPlacePicked: (result) async {
              selectedPlace = result;
              SharedPreferences prefs =
                  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              prefs.setString(
                  "Long", selectedPlace.geometry.location.lng.toString());
              prefs.setString(
                  "Lat", selectedPlace.geometry.location.lat.toString());
              // prefs.setString(
              //     "currentLoc", selectedPlace.formattedAddress.toString());
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                          BottomNavBarWidget()));

              // setState(() {});
            },
            forceSearchOnZoomChanged: true,
            enableMyLocationButton: true,
            enableMapTypeButton: true,
            usePinPointingSearch: true,
            usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
            hintText: "Search here",
            searchingText: "Searching..",
            initialMapType: MapType.hybrid,
            forceAndroidLocationManager: true,
            pinBuilder: (context, state) {
              if (state == PinState.Idle) {
                return Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.mapPin,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 25,
                );
              } else {
                return Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.locationArrow,
                  size: 20,
                );
              }
            },
          );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just the [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter/install) package (which the place picker plugin relies on to display the map), you can do something like this to get the location of an area when you tap it:

```
 final GoogleMap googleMap = GoogleMap(
     onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition: _kInitialPosition, //and/or any other parameters
      onTap: (LatLng pos) {
        setState(() {
         //assign pos value to your LatLng 
         print('${pos.latitude}, ${pos.longitude}');
        });
      },
```

Comment: You can also check out the [map_click.dart](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/map_click.dart) from the google_maps_flutter package examples